# How to find all posts without category and assign the "Uncategorized"?

Tags: categories

Hi is there anybody who can help me how to find all posts without category and assign the "Uncategorized"? I have more than 7000 posts and 300 of them are without category, how I could assing one?

And another question, how I can assign category to all posts (except bulk edit which doesnt work well with this amount of posts)?

Comment: How do you know that the 300 posts are "without category," and how did they get category-less? Is this what you get from observing the posts on the Front End or in Edit Post, or are you already returning them via function like wp_get_post_categories()? Did you move the posts from a different site or run some kind of operation on them? The answers would be relevant to what kind of fix to advise.

Comment: I know how many posts I have and how many are in the category. I have importend them manualy from another database (and some had no category and I forgot to assign).

Comment: Not sure how you're looking at the posts, but, if you use a PHP debugger or plugin like Shortcode Exec PHP, do you see an array with an empty value where a category ID ought to be? Something like Array( [0] => )?

Comment: @CKMacLeod yes, empty value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current accepted takes posts out of range too. Since it LEFT JOIN on wp_term_relationships without knowing that the first join might be a Category or a Post_tag, it gives false-positive, hence affecting posts that might not be without category.

Inspired from the current accepted answer, change the "37" for your actual wanted category:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships
(object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT p.ID as `object_id`, 37 as `term_taxonomy_id`, 0 as `term_order`
    FROM wp_posts p 
    WHERE p.post_type="post" 
        AND p.post_status='publish'
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    wp_term_relationships rel
        JOIN    wp_term_taxonomy tax
        ON      tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
                AND tax.taxonomy = 'category' 
        JOIN    wp_terms term
        ON      term.term_id = tax.term_id
        WHERE   p.ID = rel.object_id 
        )
```

Comment: Great little query that saved me some time, works as intended - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it through sql query. Add your category id instead 37.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_term_relationships
(object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order)
SELECT 
    wp_posts.ID as object_id,
    37 as term_taxonomy_id,
    0 as term_order
FROM    wp_posts
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_term_relationships rel
ON      wp_posts.ID = rel.object_id 
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_term_taxonomy tax
ON      tax.term_taxonomy_id = rel.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND tax.taxonomy = 'category' 
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_terms term
ON      term.term_id = tax.term_id
WHERE   wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
        AND term.term_id is null
```

Comment: Wow, this is kind of a reply from the future, but chapeau! Really cool and I'm going to save it somewhere for the next time.

Comment: Super efficient answer! I updated 19.470 posts within 2-3 seconds :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set any category to your post then it'll automatically be assigned to **Uncategorized**. You don't need to assign it manually to   **Uncategorized**

And for assigning category to bulk posts you can use [`wp_set_post_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories) function. Get all of your posts(which you need to assign category) in an array and run a loop theough the array with
[`wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories, $append )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories) passing needed parameter. It will assign the category to your posts.

Comment: Apparently, @kybernaut.cz is dealing with one of those instances where the database, at risk of putting too strong a word on it, has been corrupted during a transfer. That sometimes results in posts with incomplete arguments: Instead of having a previously assigned value - like a category or attachment ID, they end up with an empty value. It sounds like that's what we may be dealing with here: If the post had been normally created, it would get either the default category or Uncategorized (ID = 0 or 1, depending ). Instead, it may have an empty field. See comment above.

Comment: @CK MacLeond yes, definitely this case but the workaround with wp_set_post_categories() works just fine. Thanks a lot to both.
**the_dramatist** thanks for pointing the fuction out, that is what I was looking for, however - if your db is somehow corrupted you can have empty values (and WP is ok with it), just there is no default way to catch them all

Comment: I was writing that ` wp_set_post_categories()` will work fine in this case also. So this function will work fine.