# How to assign posts without any category to the default category

Tags: categories, bulk

Due to a massive import of posts from another cms into wordpress I have ended with thousands of posts without any category.

I need to add all those posts to the default category. I've seen this similar question asked before here: [How to find all posts without category and assign the "Uncategorized"?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251175/how-to-find-all-posts-without-category-and-assign-the-uncategorized) but my little knowledge of the subject does not allow me to know how to apply the solution.

The solution was:

> you can use `wp_set_post_categories()` function. Get all of your
>   posts(which you need to assign category) in an array and run a loop
>   theough the array with `wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories, $append )` passing needed parameter. It will assign
>   the category to your posts.

Can someone explain to me how can I create the whole function and where and when do I run it?

I want to avoid the server to run out of memory for having so many posts to change.

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_insert_post` like this:

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

use `wp_update_post` to update posts.